# Web App on Linux, cannot change virtual path

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a static html website to my App Service with the following specs:

[image]

When I ssh into the service I can see all the files were successfully dropped into `/home/site/wwwroot`. However when I go to the app service's url (`<app-service-name>.azurewebsites.net`) it still shows the default hello page.

When I go to `<app-service-name>.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot` the site is displayed correctly.

I have seen some other posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439739/how-to-use-wwwroot-folder-in-azure-thats-already-working-in-iis)) about changing the virtual directory but the setting is not present in my app service.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: The Azure portal shows only features that currently work for Web App for Containers/Linux. As more features are enabled, they will become visible on the portal. See this doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT that makes sense. However, is there a reason why the site directory is different on Linux than Windows?

Comment: For now configuration of virtual directories on Linux App Service is not supported, however you could try to implement it with .htaccess file. (Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512881/how-to-set-document-root-to-be-a-subdirectory-using-htaccess-and-not-vhost) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118941/using-htaccess-to-change-document-root))